# How can I check, if node has a new (unpublished) revision in node-template?

Tags: theming

I have user created content. I use the content-moderation plugin, so user can update their nodes but the updates will only be published after moderation. I like to display a little batch (has new unpublished update) on the user-nodes, to give the user an information about the moderation state.

For nodes with new revision in draft-state shows drupal a "last-version"-link in node-links-menü. It must be possible to check, if there is a new revision in draft state (in preprocess_node). Who can help me and write a little php code for this check so I can generate a twig_variable "has_draft_state".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you

```
{% set isNew = node.isNewRevision %}
```

Otherwise use template_preprocess_node() in your theme to generate needed variable.

Comment: Thank you, but {% node.isNewRevision %} does nothing. How can I check if node has an unpublished revision in preprocess_node()?